# Make a widened circle Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to use tikz to draw a rectangle with rounded edges like the connections on a New York City Subway map.

[image: Connection on the Subway]

More formally I am looking to draw two semicircles joined by a rectangle.

I can do this with little difficulty using a several instances of `\draw` and `\clip` but I need to draw a lot of these and my implementation is not very scalable and would require me to hand write a good deal of code for each one.  Is there anyway I could make these easily or compactly?

For reference here is the code I have come up with:

```
\documentclass{standalone}\input tikz.tex\begin{document}\tikz{
 \coordinate (left) at (0,0);
 \coordinate (right) at (.5,0);
 \begin{scope}
  \clip(-.11,-.11)rectangle(0,.11);
  \draw(left)circle(1mm);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}
  \clip(0,-.11)rectangle(.5,.11);
  \draw(-.01,-.1)rectangle(.51,.1);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}
  \clip(.5,-.11)rectangle(.61,.11);
  \draw(right)circle(1mm);
 \end{scope}
}\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a `rounded rectangle` node shape.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\usetikzlibrary{shapes}`. Then you can use rounded rectangle as @Torbjørn T has already said.

[image]

Here is a small example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, rounded rectangle,minimum width=10em] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can adjust the thickness with the option `line width` or you can rotate with the same name, the rectangle with **rounded edges**.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=3pt, rounded corners=15pt]
  (5,2) rectangle ++(3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=1pt, rotate=80, red, rounded corners=15pt]
  (5,2) rectangle ++(3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```